# Is sharing a recommendation for a paid product OK?

Tags: discussion, answers

As I'm answering questions, I've seen instances where a paid product (such as a book, screencast, etc) might help the poster further improve their original problem. Is it acceptable to recommend that product and provide a link to it?

Answer (score 6):

If you have used a particular product to solve a problem, it is ok to mention that in your answer, while also explaining how it is used to solve the problem.

It is not ok to link to a product or site in *all* your answers, or if the link is the whole answer. Especially not if it is *your* product or site.

Comment: In addition, when applicable: disclose if you're affiliated with the product.